# Magento Sagepay direct issue

Tags: magento, opayo

I have sagepay Account. I am getting an error 
Status: INVALID

Status Detail: 4006 : The TxType requested is not supported on this account.

I am using Ebizmart's extension for Magento. Please give me some idea asap.

Thanks,
Dev

Answer (score 0):

Is this a LIVE account? If its only a TEST account and you are posting to the LIVE url, you will get this message. You have to  ask Sage Pay to switch it live.

You have to contact Sagepay and ask them to enable the transaction type that’s in the TxType field.